My Office Add-in submission is not appearing in the Marketplace Offers section
After submitting my offer for Office Add-in 365 via Partner Center for publishing to Microsoft marketplace and APP Store, the certification process failed, and I received an email instructing me to check the report. However, when I clicked on the report link in the email, I encountered the following error message:
{
"CorrelationId": "xxxxxxxxx",
"CorrelationVector": "xxxxxxxxxx",
"Time": "31 Aug 2024 01:05:28 +00:00",
"Status": "Unauthorized"
}
I see the "Unauthorized" status, which is puzzling because I'm logged in with my credentials. I'm not sure what this authorization issue pertains to?However, I am unable to find submitted application in marketplace offer page in Partner Center to address the required changes and re-submit it. Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?
Marketplace offers Overview
Submission email
I am trying to find my submission to to address the required changes and re-submit it.
